# ¿Qué significa := en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, operador, python-3.8, operador-morsa

He visto código de Python , en el que se hace uso del símbolo `:=`.

*Como por ejemplo:*

```
if (variable := random.randint(1,10)) > 5:
    #Bloque de código...
```

---

No me queda claro cuál es la utilidad de este símbolo en Python.

1. *¿Qué significa este símbolo?*
2. *¿Qué hace o para que sirve este símbolo en Python?*

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### ¿Qué significa este símbolo?

Se trata del [operador walrus](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#assignment-expressions) (*operador morsa*), que fue introducido con la versión 3.8.x de Python (ver [*What’s New In Python 3.8*](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html)).

Este operador fue propuesto en el [PEP 572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/):

> **Del resumen abstracto:** This is a proposal for creating a way to assign to variables within an expression using the notation NAME := expr.
>
> **De la razón de la propuesta:** Naming the result of an expression is an important part of programming, allowing a descriptive name to be used in place of a longer expression, and permitting reuse. Currently, this feature is available only in statement form, making it unavailable in list comprehensions and other expression contexts.

### ¿Qué hace o para que sirve este símbolo en Python?

Cumple la misma función con la que fue propuesta en primer lugar: **asignar un valor a una variable y que se evalúe como expresión.**

Anteriormente, si se quería evaluar una expresión y utilizar ese resultado como variable, se tenía que definir una variable y después evaluarla.

```
import random

variable = random.randint(1,10) 

if variable > 5:
    print(f"El número {variable} es mayor a 5")
else:
    print(f"El número {variable} es menor a 5")
```

Si se trata de hacer una asignación en el condicional para evaluar la condición y tener una variable que almacene el resultado de la expresión:

```
if (variable = random.randint(1,10)) > 5:
    print(f"El número {variable} es mayor a 5")
else:
    print(f"El número {variable} es menor a 5")
```

Se obtiene un error de sintaxis:

```
    if (variable = random.randint(1,10)) > 5:
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Por la tanto antes de la versión 3.8.x, era imposible evaluar y asignar en una misma expresión. Desde que Python ofrece la opción de expresiones asignadoras con el operador de walrus, sí es posible:

```
if (variable := random.randint(1,10)) > 5:
    print(f"El resultado de la {variable} es mayor a 5")
else:
    print(f"El número {variable} es menor a 5")
```

A grandes rasgos, con este operador se puede asignar un valor a una variable y evaluar su expresión al mismo tiempo. Esto puede ser útil en ciertas situaciones, donde se ocupe reutilizar el resultado de una función, y de esta manera no llamarla más de una vez. Véase el ejemplo en el articulo de [*What’s New In Python 3.8*](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html)

```
if (cantidad_elementos := len(lista)) > 10:
    print(f"Lista demasiado larga ({cantidad_elementos} elementos, se esperaban <= 10)")
```

Esto evita volver a llamar a `len()` a la hora de formatear el mensaje a mostrar, directamente se llama a la variable definida `cantidad_elementos`.

Comment: ¿Se puede usar en versiones anteriores usando `future`?

Comment: No lo sé, desconozco que es `future`.

Comment: No, porque anteriormente no existía el operador. `future` hasta donde sé, se usa para evitar romper código ya existente (por ejemplo si un operador cambia de comportamiento de una versión a otra), no para usar operadores de versiones más nuevas.

Comment: @Gabitohh. Usando `from __future__ import`?

Comment: @CandidMoe no sé si estoy equivocado, pero viendo [esta lista](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__future__.html) no se ve nada sobre el operador en cuestión.

Answer (score 8):

Tener el operador *walrus* nos permite no tener que [repetir código](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_te_repitas) para hacer lo mismo. Por poner un ejemplo claro, veamos lo que sería un bucle para toma de decisiones:

```py
while (sel:=input("Introduce un comando ('quit' para salir): ") != "quit":
   if sel == "comando1":
     ...
   elif sel == "comando2":
     ...
```

Hasta ahora había que repetir la línea *input* para que funcionara:

```py
sel = input("Introduce un comando ('quit' para salir): ")
while sel != "quit":
   if sel == "comando1":
     ...
   elif sel == "comando2":
     ...

   sel = input("Introduce un comando ('quit' para salir): ")
```

O meter un `break` en el bucle, lo que acababa siendo un código difícil de mantener:

```py
while True:
   sel = input("Introduce un comando ('quit' para salir): ")
   if sel == "quit":
       break
   elif sel == "comando1":
     ...
   elif sel == "comando2":
     ...
```

Pero quizás donde luzca más este operador sea con las compresiones de listas y expresiones generadoras. Por ejemplo: imaginemos que queremos obtener un listado de factoriales de los 100 primeros números naturales:

```py
def factorial(n):
    res = 1
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        res *= i
    return

lista_factoriales = [factorial(i) for i in range(1, 100)]
```

Sería un modo muy poco eficiente, ya que no estamos aprovechado que tenemos el factorial de un número para calcular el siguiente. Si embargo, ahora sí que se puede hacer con el *operador walrus*, así de simple:

```py
a = 1
lista_factoriales = [a := a*i for i in range(1, 100)]
```

Por poner otro ejemplo más sofisticado, así se podría calcular los primeros 100 elementos de la sucesión de Fibonacci:

```py
(a, b) = (0, 1)
fib = [(c:=a+b, a:=b, b:=c)[1] for _ in range(100)]
```