# Sintaxis if en python

Tags: python, sintaxis

Soy nuevo en *Python*, estoy intentando guardar un cálculo en una variable (`tria`) y comparar ese resultado con otro valor (todo esto escrito en la misma línea). El editor produce un error de sintaxis, en otros lenguajes como *C* basta con colocar un paréntesis para que el compilador sepa que debe calcular, guardar el resultado y después realizar la comparación.

Mi pregunta puntual es, ¿Por qué no se puede hacer?

```py
def trill(numeros):
    trillizos = []
    indice = 0
    while indice + 2 != len(numeros)-1:
        if (tria = sum(numeros[indice : indice+2])) == 0:
            trillizos.append(tria)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que en python, el `=` no te regresa el valor. Tu lo que estas buscando es el operador Walrus.

Prueba el siguiente codigo en el interprete (Tiene que ser python 3.8):

```
>>> walrus = False
>>> print(walrus)
False
>>> print(walrus := True)
True
```

Y te recomiendo que leas esta pregunta: [¿Qué significa := en Python?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/386750/qu%c3%a9-significa-en-python/388961#388961)

Eso o haces el calculo afuera, una de 2

Comment: También puede hacerse con un `lambda`.