# Cómo pintar los elementos de una tupla sin corchetes

Tags: python, tuplas

Tengo que realizar esto: Crear una función para multiplicar los valores recibidos de tipo numérico, utilizando argumentos variables *args como parámetro de la función y regresar como resultado la multiplicación de todos los valores pasados como argumentos.

Este es mi código:

```
def multiplicacion(*args):
   numero = 1
   for j in args:
       numero *= j
   return numero

lista_numeros = []
numeros = input('Ingrese los numeros a multiplicar:').split()
print(numeros)
for i in numeros:
    i = int(i)
    lista_numeros.append(i)
print(f'la lista es: {lista_numeros}')
print(multiplicacion(lista_numeros))
```

---

Lo que sucede es que al imprimir "print(multiplicacion(lista_numeros))" en vez de arrojarme el valor de la multiplicación de los valores en la lista, me imprime la lista como tupla. ¿Cúal es el error?

Comment: solución: haz `for j in args[0]:`

Answer (score 4):

Los argumentos variables son representados u obtenidos en forma de tuplas, por lo que en realidad tu parámetro `args` se ve así

```
([elementos])
```

Y al hacer `for j in args` estas iterando en esa tupla, que solo contiene un elemento, por lo que la variable `j` toma el valor de la lista y al multiplicarse por 1 sigue sin variar. Por lo que la solución es simplemente es acceder al primer elemento de la tupla, que vendría a ser la lista que realmente pasas.

```py
def multiplicacion(*args):
   numero = 1
   for j in args[0]:
       numero *= j
   return numero
```

Y con esto digo que la forma en que pasas los parámetros está mal bajo tu concepto de argumentos variables, ya que **siempre** pasarás 1 lista de números. Si en realidad deseas pasar varios argumentos contenidos en una lista debes de *desempaquetarlo* y eso se hace con el símbolo `*`.

Tu código quedaría así (resumí un ciclo usando comprensión de listas):

```py
def multiplicacion(*args):
   numero = 1
   for j in args: #aqui si recibimos varios argumentos por lo que no hay que cambiar nada 
       numero *= j
   return numero


numeros = input('Ingrese los numeros a multiplicar:').split()
print(numeros)
lista_numeros = [int(i) for i in numeros]
print(f'la lista es: {lista_numeros}')
print(multiplicacion(*lista_numeros)) #desempaquetamos la lista, lo que provoca que cada elemento se pase como un parámetro
```

Answer (score 0):

Estás pintando la tupla directamente, hazlo elemento a elemento:

```
for numero in lista_numeros:
    print(str(numero) + ' ')
```

Comment: Nota: La pregunta usa python 3 y no 2, ¿Cual es la diferencia?: Puede confundir al usuario la forma de llamar a print, si llamas a print de esta forma: `print "hello world";` en python 2 mostrará el texto por la pantalla y en python 3 dará un error y eso puede confundir aun mas al usuario porque está usando la version 3 del interprete python.

Comment: @DanielBriceño ¡Gracias! Lo he cambiado para usar print como función.

Comment: sabes que esa no es la solución?

Comment: Si me permites mejorar aun mas la respuesta agregas en el bucle de la funcion multipricar numeros: `for j in args[0]:` porque parece que el interprete convierte el contenido del argumento `*args` en otro arreglo: Ejemplo: `hola([1,2,3]);` `def hola(*args):    print(args);` output: `([1,2,3],)` por lo visto lo convierte en una turpa y por eso debemos especificar en el bucle que queremos solo el primer elemento(Pues la funcion solo se iso para una lista).

Comment: @DanielBriceño en mi respuesta explico eso :D

Comment: Je. Voy a recarga la pagina.

Answer (score 0):

Dado que el ejercicio es a nivel educativo, ***en versiones modernas de python*** tambien podrías usar una *conprensión de listas* y el *operador morsa*

```
def multiplicacion(*args):
    prod = 1
    return [prod := (n*prod) for n in args[0]][-1]
```

Generas una lista con los productos

```
lista =[prod := (n*prod) for n in args[0]]
```

y devuelves el último valor de la lista.

```
return lista[-1]
```

En una una *conprensión de listas* **NO** está permitida la expresión `prod = n * prod`.

Pero desde **python 3.8** el **operador morsa** `prod := (n*prod)` nos permite asignar un valor y devolverlo en la misma expresión.

[Aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/386750/qu%C3%A9-significa-en-python) hay varias respuestas explicando qué es y como utilizarlo. Me parecieron muy interesantes los ejemplos de @ChemaCortes para generar la lista de factoriales y la serie de fibonacci.

Comment: No conozco el operador "morsa". No entiendo esta solución. Si explicaras como funciona sería estupendo.

Comment: @CandidMoe me parecía una forma muy poco eficiente y solo pretendía proponer otro tipo de solución. Y eso me gustaría preguntarte. ¿Cómo de eficiente sería utilizar esta solución? ¿Es una barbaridad?

Comment: No conozco el operador "morsa". Tendre que estudiar el tema.

Comment: Yo no soy experto en el tema, pero usando un toque de sentido común, creo que crear una lista solo para tomar el ultimo elemento y dejarla en el olvido es un gasto innecesario de memoria y velocidad. Por que estarías creando la lista y guardando valores que no serán usados. Las comprensiones pueden ser muy utiles A VECES, pero no sirven en todos los casos.

Comment: Gracias @DanteS. , solo lo puse a nivel de investigación y porque me recordó a los ejemplos que había en esta página. Hice pruebas de tiempos de ejecución y me sorprendió que al multiplicar los 1.000 primeros números ( 1 - 1001) se pierden 0.000463seg. (es la media de 100 ejecuciones). Aunque no sé valorarlo, resultó menos de lo que esperaba.