# Trato de ordenar un vector de mayo a menor con el método burbuja

Tags: python

## Se requiere conocer los N primeros números de la serie Fibonacci

para
las semillas X y Y.
Se entiende la serie Fibonacci como aquella que se construye sumando
los últimos dosnúmeros de la serie.

La construcción de la serie se basará en la hora exacta del día en que se produce.

los minutos de las horas serán la semilla de la serie, así como los segundos serán la cantidad
de números que se deben mostrar.
Por ejemplo, si la ejecución ocurre a las 14:23:04, las semillas de la serie serán 2 y 3, y se
deben producer 04 números (Sin contar las semillas) de forma descendente así:
21,13,8,5,3,2.
Otro ejemplo podría ser 15:49:08 donde las semillas de la serie serán 4 y 9, y se deben
producir 08 número así 241, 149, 92, 57, 35, 22, 13, 9, 4

```
import time
print("La Hora es: "+ (time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")) )
minuto = (time.strftime("%M"))
semillaX = int(minuto[0])
semillaY = int(minuto[1])``

segundo = (time.strftime("%S"))
serie = int(segundo)
print(semillaX)

def fibonacci(n):

    a = semillaX
    b = semillaY 

    for e in range(n):
      c = a+b
      a = b
      b = c

    return b
for i in range(serie+1):
    print(fibonacci(i))


# metodo burbuja



for j in range(len(semillaX) - 1):
      if semillaX[j] < semillaX[j+1]:
       aux = semillaX[j]
       semillaX[j] = semillaX[j+1]
       semillaX[j+1] = aux
print(semillaX)
```

Comment: Consulta querés ordenarlos con bublesort por algo en particular? los número de Fibonacci vienen siempre ordenados de forma creciente (i.e. de menor a mayor) si los necesitás al reves, lo más fácil es directamente invertir el array indexando: si acomodás tu código para obtener todos los valores en un array podés hacer `fibo[::-1]` esto dice: desde el primer elemento al último del array con paso -1 (entiende que tiene que arrancar por el final y llegar al primero).

Comment: @UlisesBussi No quiero ordenarlos con bublesort por particular solo estoy tratando de imprimir la serie Fibonacci de mayor a menor (O sea invertirlos) he tratado con diferentes métodos y aun no lo he logrado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si usas python 3.8 o superior puedes crear la función con una comprensión de listas usando el **operador morsa**.

```
from time import time, strftime

print("La Hora es: "+ (strftime("%H:%M:%S")) )
minuto = (strftime("%M"))
a, b = int(minuto[0]), int(minuto[1])
veces = int(strftime("%S"))

print([(a, c:=a+b, a:=b, b:=c)[0] for _ in range(veces)][::-1] )
```

[Info sabre operador morsa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/386750/qu%C3%A9-significa-en-python)

Para invertir la lista: `lista[::-1]`

Comment: La función me sirve pero ahora entre en otro problema al momento de imprimir invertido necesito que me registre ambos minutos, solo me esta registra el segundo minuto el primero no..

Comment: Ya está editado, creo que ahora imprime desde el 0

Comment: Si ya lo solucione, modifique el 1 por el 0, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

te propongo esta solución para tu problema

```
import time

def fibonacci(semillaX,semillaY,serie):
    resultado=[semillaX,semillaY]
    for i in range(serie):
        resultado.append(resultado[-1]+resultado[-2])
    return resultado[::-1]

print("La Hora es: "+ (time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")) )
minuto = (time.strftime("%M"))
semillaX = int(minuto[0])
semillaY = int(minuto[1])
serie = int((time.strftime("%S")))
print(fibonacci(semillaX,semillaY,serie))
```

Este código retorna los datos como tu quieres ej. 21,13,8,5,3,2. Si quieres que lo retorne como 2,3,5,8,13,21 tienes que cambiar lo siguiente:

```
import time

def fibonacci(semillaX,semillaY,serie):
    resultado=[semillaX,semillaY]
    for i in range(serie):
        resultado.append(resultado[-1]+resultado[-2])
    return resultado

print("La Hora es: "+ (time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")) )
minuto = (time.strftime("%M"))
semillaX = int(minuto[0])
semillaY = int(minuto[1])
serie = int((time.strftime("%S")))
print(fibonacci(semillaX,semillaY,serie))
```

Espero te sirva

Comment: he tratado con la invertida y al momento de correrlo solo me registra la hora pero no me imprime absolutamente nada mas.

Comment: claro, perdón yo hice el código en jupyter notebook y se me olvido mandar a impirmir. Ahorita edito la respuesta para que funcione

Comment: Tranquilo, mil  gracias.

Comment: Yo soy nuevo en stackoverflow y no puedo poner un comentario en la respuesta de Tomy. Para que quede como quieres usando su propuesta debes de sumar 2 a veces. Puede que ya te hayas dado cuenta de eso pero solo quería hacer la anotación. Otra cosa me podrías ayudar dandole puntos a mi respuesta para poder ir subiendo de nivel :)

Comment: Ya lo solucione, muchas gracias ahi te colabore.

Comment: muchas gracias bonito dia