# Input en Python de un texto con varios párrafos

Tags: python

Buen día para todos.

Estoy aprendiendo Python y quisiera saber si es posible solicitar por pantalla a un usuario un texto largo con varios párrafos, ya sea escrito manualmente o copy+paste.
Intente usar un input pero al hacer un salto de línea, el input se cierra o termina de recibir texto.

La finalidad de esto en contexto es solicitar al usuario que digite o copie un texto donde explique una receta de cocina y al terminar, dicha receta se agregue a un archivo previamente creado con el nombre de la receta.

Desde ya muchas gracias y espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: En su estado actual, la _pregunta_ parece más una solicitud para que alguien haga tu tarea. StackOverflow está diseñado para que hagas una pregunta específica (una sola), y la comunidad reacciona mejor si agregas el código de lo que has intentado y una explicación del problema que te da o por qué eso no te funciona, junto a lo que quisieras lograr. Encontrás más información en [ask].

Comment: En este caso particular, estaría bueno que demostrases tu esfuerzo agregando algunos links que visitaste pero no respondieron tu duda. Sin embargo, te diré que no existe una forma sencilla incluida en Python de hacer eso. Tal vez lo puedas lograr con librerías como blessed, que te dan mucho más control de la consola.

Comment: Si no quieres que el salto de línea sea el final del input, ¿cómo esperas que el usuario indique que ha terminado de introducir el input?

Comment: Hola Everth Barrera, bienvenido, creo que no tiene sentido lo que pides, ya que si la entrada la va a realizar un usuario, debes tener una interfaz de usuario,, en la que puedes poner un campo en el que escribir lo que sea, y luego mediante un botón, ingresarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cada vez que el usuario presione salto de línea será el final de un párrafo.
Puedes guardarte todos los párrafos en una lista y después concatenarlos con el símbolo de salto de línea: `\n`.

```
parrafos = []
print("Introduce tu texto")
while parrafo := input():
    parrafos.append(parrafo)
texto_completo = '\n'.join(parrafos)
```

Este código recibirá párrafos hasta que el usuario pulse dos veces seguidas la tecla de salto de línea.
Todo lo que haya escrito el usuario lo tendrás en una variable.
Escribir su contenido en un archivo de texto se hace de forma rutinaria.

Comment: Oh, mi conclusión fue precipitada y sin pruebas. Si dices que me equivoqué, no puedo contradecirlo. Gracias por el aviso, borro comentario.

Comment: Jorge Luis que brutal eres, la probé dentro de mi código y justamente era lo que necesitaba, que Genialidad la tuya, muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Deberías especificar que el operador walrus (morsa) está disponible a partir de la versión 3.8. Además podrías proponer la solución para versiones anteriores

Comment: Por petición de @Christian para quien esté usando una versión de Python anterior a la 3.8 dejo esta respuesta que explica cómo escribir un bucle equivalente: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/388961/265345
Aunque más importante es que sepas que el 27 de junio de 2023 termina el mantenimiento de la última versión de Python sin `:=`.