# NameError al intentar ejecutar

Tags: python

Cuando intento ejecutar el código me da error en los "menu" que aparecen después del `while`:

```
def main(): 
    menu= {
        "Burrito":7.50,
        "Baja taco":4.00,
        "Bowl":8.50,
        "Nachos":11.00,
        "Quesadilla":8.50,
        "Super Burrito":8.50,
        "Super Quesadilla":9.50,
        "Taco":3.00,
        "Tortilla Salad":8.00
    }

order_total = 0.0
while True:
    try:
        Item=input("Ingrese un artículo a su pedido:")
    except EOFError:
      break
    Item = Item.upper()
    if Item in menu:
        order_total += menu[Item]
    elif Item == "CONTROL-D":
        print(f"EL total de su pedido es de ${order_total:.2f}")
        break
    else:
        print("Artículo inválido")
if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

me da error en los menú después del "break"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Stiven, agrega siempre el código como texto no  como una imagen. Si compartes tu código usando una imagen haces muy difícil su reproducción por parte de otros usuarios, entorpeces su visualización en dispositivos móviles, no indexa en búsquedas, etc... [Edita tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/608802/edit), copia y pega el código como texto, luego lo seleccionas todo y pulsas `Ctrl + k` o el botón `{}` del editor para darle formato. Deberías agregar también el error que tienes en concreto.

Comment: El método `.upper()` devuelve el string completamente en mayúsculas, `"BURRITO"` y no `"Burrito"`. No sé qué error (la línea amarilla no es un error, es un warning por cierto!) te está marcando, pero el código nunca te va a funcionar tal como está.

Answer (score 0):

El error se debe a un error de identacion, las lineas de la 14 a la 27 (incluidas) están fuera de la funcion `main` porque les faltan un nivel de sangrado. Esto hace que `menu` (definida dentro de `main`) no exista a nivel global (ámbito al que pertenece la linea `if Item in menu` por el error de sangrado).

Dicho esto, tienes mas problemas en ese código:

```
except EOFError:
  break
```

esto hace que el ciclo termine inmediatamente si el usuario pulsa Ctrl + D sin imprimir el total y no parece que quieras eso. Ademas, el elif:

```
elif Item == "CONTROL-D":
```

jamas se va a ejecutar, primero por el `break` anterior que rompe el ciclo inmediatamente, segundo porque si se pulsa Ctrl + D se produce una excepción y la asignación:

```
Item=input("Ingrese un artículo a su pedido:")
```

jamas tiene lugar. Es decir, a `Item` no se le asigna "CONTROL-D", la excepción para empezar evita que esa asignación se complete. Item no sera definida siquiera (si es la primera iteración del ciclo) o tendrá el valor asignado en la iteración anterior.

Por otro lado, `str.upper()` retorna una copia de la cadena con todos los caracteres en mayúscula. Tus claves en el diccionario menú no tienen todos los caracteres en mayúsculas, por lo que el `if` jamas se cumplirá. Lo que si podrías usar el `str.title`:

```
>>> cad = "super queSadilla"
>>> cad.upper()
'SUPER QUESADILLA'
>>> cad.title()
'Super Quesadilla'
```

Con todo lo comentado, tu código podría quedar:

```
def main(): 
    menu= {
        "Burrito": 7.50,
        "Baja taco": 4.00,
        "Bowl": 8.50,
        "Nachos": 11.00,
        "Quesadilla": 8.50,
        "Super Burrito": 8.50,
        "Super Quesadilla": 9.50,
        "Taco": 3.00,
        "Tortilla Salad": 8.00
    }

    order_total = 0.0
    while True:
        try:
            item = input("Ingrese un artículo a su pedido: ").title()
        except EOFError:
            print(f"\nEL total de su pedido es de ${order_total:.2f}")
            break
        
        if valor:= menu.get(item):
            order_total += valor
        else:
            print("Artículo inválido")
            
if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

---

En:

```
if valor:= menu.get(item):
    order_total += valor
```

se usa el [operador "morsa"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/386750/qu%C3%A9-significa-en-python) junto a `dict.get()`, si te confunde o no quieres hacer uso del mismo puedes hacer:

```
if item in menu:
    order_total += menu[item]
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que estás haciendo es hacer el while antes de que esté definido menú, por eso no te lo colorea en azul, para eso debes meter todo el bucle (while) dentro del main().
El try también lo podrías quitar, no entiendo por qué lo has puesto.
El menú también se podría definir como un diccionario global aunque no es necesario.
Por último, creo que lo que quieres hacer cuando haces el .upper() es un .title() para convertir la primera letra de cada palabra en mayuscula y no todas.\

Resuelto y mejorado:

```
menu = {
        'Salsa Car': 5
    }
def main():
    order_total = 0.0
    while True:
        # Capitalizo todas las palabras de la entrada. Nota: capitalize solo capitaliza la primera palabra
        Item = str(input('Pedido: ')).title()
        if Item in menu.keys():
            order_total += menu[Item]
        elif Item.upper() == 'CONTROL-D':
            return order_total
        else:
            print('tarará')
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    order = main()
    print(order)
```